# GWT theme style overrides my css style

Tags: css, gwt, themes

I have some html files with their own css. I want to use them in a gwt application so i copied the html and the css files in the application.

The problem is when i open the html it uses the gwt theme style. For example in my css the html 'body' background color is black, but it looks white unless i deactivate the theme.

How could I override the gwt theme style and use my css styles?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Like Sarfaz said - `!important` should be your last resort as it kind of defeats the whole concept of **Cascading** Style Sheets.

Anyway, in GWT, in order to easily override the core GWT styles contained in the theme you selected, you should locate your module file (the one that has a file name ending on *.gwt.xml), then locate the line where you declare your theme and put your custom/whatever stylesheet *after* it, like this:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard' />
<stylesheet src="CustomStylesheet.css" />
```

Note, however, that for GWT 2.0 [`CssResource`](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#CssResource) and [UiBinder](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_Stylish_World) is recommended.

Be sure to read the [appropriate section](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html) of the docs for more pointers.

Comment: using the <stylesheet tag in the module XML no longer works. the docs say it is deprecated, but it has no effect. it's quite hard to believe that they'd make the default behavior such that the stock themes take precedence over the app's custom styles.

Comment: Interesting info about `<stylesheet>` being deprecated - but I'm not sure this warrants a down vote (whoever cast it ;)), since the other info is still valid (`CssResource` and/or UiBinder). Have you tried adding the style sheet in your HTML host file via the standard `<link>` tag? Or if you do come up with a working/not deprecated way to override the default theme, please share it with the rest of the community - I'm sure it will be appreciated :)

Comment: I'm looking or an answer to this question too as I can't seem to override the default styles (the stylesheet tag has been taken away).

Comment: `CustomStylesheet.css` has to be located inside a folder named `public` which has to be in the same directory as your `*.gwt.xml` file. See also [Overriding GWT's default stylesheet](http://www.jeanhsu.com/2010/04/29/overriding-gwts-default-stylesheet/).

Comment: I had to add a slash '/' in front of the file name like `<stylesheet src="/CustomStylesheet.css" />` then it works with the css file in the `war` directory.

Answer (score 37):

This [post](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/msg/c2686706b45b8f60) on the GWT mailing list describes an alternative solution. You have to create a new `ClientBundle` which references your CSS file:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.resources.client.ClientBundle;
import com.google.gwt.resources.client.CssResource;

public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {

      public static final Resources INSTANCE = GWT.create(Resources.class); 

      @Source("style.css")
      @CssResource.NotStrict
      CssResource css();
}
```

And then inside your `onModuleLoad()` method you have to [inject](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/StyleInjector) the CSS file:

```
public class YourApp implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        //...
        Resources.INSTANCE.css().ensureInjected(); 
        //...
    }
```

In my opinion this is the cleanest and easiest way to override the styles.

Comment: my god, finally a REAL solution. please accept my upvote as a toke of thanks.

Comment: Thanks! this worked for me. I removed the CSS in the webcontent folder y moved it to the xxx.client . Because @Source will throw an error.

Answer (score 6):

You can override the styles of GWT by using the keyword `!important` in all your css of the html files, for example, if one of your html file contains this css:

```
background-color:#000000;
```

Then you should write it like this:

```
background-color:#000000 !important;
```

Do the same for all your styles in html files.

Note that using `!important` is not the best way, if you can find any *better* alternatives you should go for them first.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using `!important` you can also rely on [CSS Selector Specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Most (all?) of the GWT styles are stated using just class eg:

```
.gwt-DisclosurePanel .header {
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

To override this you can use `!important` **or** you can be more specific in your selectors eg:

```
table.gwt-DisclosurePanel .header {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

*How does this work?* This works because adding the element name (table) to the class in the selector makes it more specific than just the class alone. This will override other styles even from stylesheets listed lower in the header.

Giving your widgets IDs and using those is even more specific.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not very elegant but I found it rather effective to replace the `standard.css` file in the output files generated by GWT with an **empty file**.

(Maven can take care of that reliably.)

Answer (score 2):

The solution `<stylesheet src="CustomStylesheet.css" />` is [deprecated](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html) and did not work with the new superdevmode.

A solution that worked for me (using GWT 2.7) was to create a new custom theme:

**projectPackage/themes/MyCustomTheme/MyCustomTheme.gwt.xml**

```
<module>
    <stylesheet src="gwt/MyCustomTheme/MyCss.css"/>
</module>
```

**projectPackage/themes/MyCustomTheme/MyCustomThemeRessources.gwt.xml**

```
</module>
```

**projectPackage/themes/MyCustomTheme/public/gwt/MyCustomTheme/MyCss.css**
(Note: removing the gwt/MyCustomTheme/ part of the path worked in devmode but didn't work in deployed version, of cause you can still rename 'MyCustomTheme' to something of your liking)

> The css file you want to use

**Project.gwt.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.0//EN"
        "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/releases/2.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to="Project">

(...)

<!-- Inherit GWT theme.  e.g. the Clean theme -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
<!-- Our custom theme      -->
<inherits name='projectPackage.themes.MyCustomTheme.MyCustomTheme'/>

(...)

</module>
```

Note: You can get a sample custom theme using http://gwt-theme-generator.appspot.com/ and extracting the downloaded .jar file.

Comment: Please check your code of `MyCustomThemeRessources.gwt.xml`, there is something missing in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy. Just put your CSS link *under* the GWT's module script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myapp/myapp.nocache.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="myapp.css" type="text/css">
```