# How to access/style horizontal split view's split

Tags: java, css, gwt

I'm trying to set the style name of the `div` of the split between the two widgets of a `HorizontalSplitPanel` in order to CSS-style it. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the javadocs for [`HorizontalSplitPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HorizontalSplitPanel.html), you should change the `.gwt-HorizontalSplitPanel .hsplitter { the splitter }` style. Just make sure you [set up your CSS styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322779/gwt-theme-style-overrides-my-css-style/2323620#2323620) to take precedence over the core GWT ones.

Answer (score 0):

Figured a way out myself, though it is definitely a bit "hacky":

```
    Element split = (Element)hSplit.getElement().getChild( 0 ).getChild( 1 );
    split.setClassName( css.horizontalSplit() );
```

If anyone has a more elegant solution, I'd love to hear it.