# What should I do to prevent GWT from using its theme and totally use the CSS that I specify

Tags: css, gwt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GWT theme style overrides my css style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322779/gwt-theme-style-overrides-my-css-style)

What should I do to prevent GWT from using its theme and totally use the CSS that I specify?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can be radical and just remove the CSS files that are in the com.google.gwt,user.theme.chrome/dark/standard packages (don't forget to remove then from the gwt.xml file). Then specify your own CSS....disadvantage is that you have to style absolutely everything yourself. Hope this helps.