# How to disable hover effect to highlight menu items in GWT MenuBar?

Tags: gwt, menu, tabs, menuitem

I am making a vertical Menu using GWT MenuBar and selection of particular MenuItem shows content on the right, I am trying to make something similar to TabPanel, but with Tabs on left instead of being on top. Now, since I've got the Menu items and actions in place, I want to remove the effect of hovering over and changing color, and keep that menu item selected which was clicked last and whose content is loaded on the right.
I am open to any comments, if you have a better solution to implement this, using some other components(with-in) GWT, please drop in a comment with your suggestions, I'll really appreciate that.
Or if you can just tell me how can I disable this effect, of hovering and sticking to only that selection, That would be awesome too..
Thanks to everyone, taking time to read this and suggesting a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's all defined in the CSS of your GWT's theme (probably the default one), so it's a matter of overriding those styles - [make sure it's not the other way around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322779/gwt-theme-style-overrides-my-css-style) :) Inspect the code with a tool like Firebug to see what's exactly being set and change that.

Comment: I have the same problem. I didn't find out how to make it with css. I found only _.gwt-MenuItem-selected_ and that didn't solve it. My question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455796/gwt-menuitem-loses-focus-after-selection).