# GWT MenuItem loses focus after selection

Tags: gwt, menuitem, menubar

I have a simple vertical one-dimensional menu. Menu items are not fix, they change dynamically according to data received from the server. (So I cannot write fix code for them.)

**In css I declared selected MenuItem to be bold.
My wish is simply to make the selected MenuItem remain bold after selection. But when I click it, it loses focus and the first MenuItem becomes bold.**

How could that be fixed?

Comment: Its really hard to say exact issue without looking at the code. May be after the selection you can set the focus and bold to the selected item again.it might work