# GWT- overriding theme CSS

Tags: css, gwt

I have a typical GWT app, in my module.xml, I have,

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard' />
```

to import a theme. in my module CSS, i have things like,

```
a:link {
    color: #eee;
}
```

however, when I run my app, the style above is overridden by something in "chrome.css". shouldn't my CSS be loaded *after* the theme CSS? otherwise, I'm stuck with the theme CSS unless I use !important, which must be wrong.

any ideas?

Comment: use: `color: #eee !important;`

Comment: !important removes the "C" from CSS, very bad. there must be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, a solution amongst all the mis-information,
[GWT theme style overrides my css style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322779/gwt-theme-style-overrides-my-css-style)

See comment: "You have to create a new ClientBundle which references your CSS file".