# How to override default styles in GWT without using !important

Tags: java, html, css, gwt

The GWT module comes with some annoying quirks, one of which is departing from the the standard font-size of `16px` and declaring it to be `12px` instead. I tried to declare individual font-size for different elements, for the body itself, but they were always overridden by the default style.

So I decided to use `!important` to declare the default font-size for the entire body. This works, problem is that it also applies to where it shouldn't, like `h2` elements. Declaring another font-size property for `h2` with another `!important` again doesn't override the one declared for the `body` element, even though it should.

So is there any way to do this? Same problem goes for the font family also, i can't override it without using `!important`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normally better to use [css specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) to override styles.

As long as your additional rule has a higher specificity than the rule you are trying to override, it should work.

Comment: Then you will need to provide a specific example which doesn't work.  Give the rule you are trying to override and your attempt to override it which is not working.

Comment: For example there's a `div` of id `foo` which contains the `h2`. I am declaring the style with specificity `div#foo h2`...

Comment: But how is the default style defined?

Comment: No idea. Probably internally. I just added another layer, set an id for the `h2` itself, and declared the style like `div#foo h2#boo`, still no luck..:)

Comment: Use firebug or something like it to examine the element and see which style is being used.  Just randomly guessing isn't the best approach.

Comment: Yeah, I have been Firebugging every step I do with GWT!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to customize a standard theme, you should *fork* it: copy/paste and adapt to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your own css and override standard.css, Hope the following link helps you

[GWT theme style overrides my css style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322779/gwt-theme-style-overrides-my-css-style)

Comment: Wow. That's a clinical link! Thanks!