# Creating my own GWT Button CSS stylr

Tags: css, gwt

I want to set a custom background for all my Buttons in my GWT app.  I'm using the standard GWT Button class.  So ( As recommended by one of the guys in SO ) in my CSS file I have

```
.gwt-Button
{
background-color: red;
}
```

However this does not get applied to my Button.  Then I tried

```
myButton.setStyleName("gwt-Button");
```

Same result.  I then changed the name of the style to "gwt.Button1" , set this as my style name and hey presto it works.  So investigating why I couldn't modify the inbuilt CSS style I noticed that when I compiled my GWT project ( I'm using Eclipse ) that in my WAR folder there is a folder created called war/myModule/gwt/standard   and in this folder are CSS files which contain the default GWT styles. ( At least that's my take on it )  So my question is how do I apply my own styling to gwt-Button and why are these css files being put in this folder and can I change these?

Comment: You didn't found any css folder above the standard folder ?

Comment: sorry,  I didn't get the folder path exact.  it's war/myModule/gwt/standard.  My own CSS files are at the root level of /war/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Project --->
|
Src
|
package com.xxxxx
|
|
folder(resources(any))
|
|
css(folder)
|
|
YourcssFile.css(write your css here )
```

Refer :https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss#cssfiles

And in GWT.xml file

```
<stylesheet src='css/YourcssFile.css' />
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the below link should solve your problem

[GWT theme style overrides my css style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322779/gwt-theme-style-overrides-my-css-style)

If not revert back. Cheers :)