# gwt radio button style using css

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder, gwtp

I tried to change the style of gwt radio button style and couldn't succeed.

Is it possible to change the gwt radio button style directly? If No what else should I do to change it.

I tried input[type="radio"]{ } in css, this doesn't help.

[image]

Thanks,
Bennet.

Comment: I thought input radio was one of those elements that can't be styled...

Comment: But, we must be able to fix this by using input element in UiBinders, right? I tried to do that. even then its not working. What might be the reason. I added the style in Uibinders itself and in css but no use, its not changing at all. what might be wrong from my side.

Comment: @Bennet what exactly do you mean by "change the style of gwt radio button" what exact change?

Comment: @Bennet check if my answer suits your needs..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what i think from your question i made a sample, check if it suits your needs

Add the following css class to your application css

```
.gwt-RadioButton {
background-color: grey;
border: 1px solid #FFFF00;
margin: 10px;
font-size: 2em;
}
```

No need to add any `addStyleNames` as the `RadioButton` by deafult listens to the `.gwt-RadioButton` css class. The Result after applying above css is something like this,

[image]

**EDITS :**

After you provided the above sample it is very clear what you want. The `.gwt-RadioButton` allows you to style the `RadioButton`. What you want is to style the radio circle and the color when it gets selected. In order to do that you need to modify the `input[type=radio]` class and the `label` present with the `RadioButton`.

What we are doing here is disabling the default radio circle using display none and adding our own as a `label:before` content and then styling it. Hope this solves your problem.
Some Styles that you need to add and then play around to suit your needs are as follows.

```
label {  
    display: inline-block;  
    cursor: pointer;  
    position: relative;  
    padding-left: 25px;  
    margin-right: 15px;  
    font-size: 13px;  
}

input[type=radio] {  
    display: none;  
}

label:before {  
    content: "";  
    display: inline-block;  

    width: 16px;  
    height: 16px;  

    margin-right: 10px;  
    position: absolute;  
    left: 0;  
    bottombottom: 1px;  
    background-color: #282E5A;  
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);  
}
.gwt-RadioButton label:before {  
    border-radius: 8px;  
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {  
    content: "\2022";  
    color: aqua;  
    font-size: 30px;  
    text-align: center;  
    line-height: 18px;  
}
```

Comment: I need something like in my question. It should be possible, but i dont know how. please help me.

Comment: @Bennet check the modified answer.

Comment: Good answer really nice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override **gwt-RadioButton** Css. For that you need to define a ClientBundle with CSSResource and inject it on your module load.

You may refer to 
[how to override gwt default css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322779/gwt-theme-style-overrides-my-css-style)